# A/Bingo not writing conversions correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, ab-testing

I'm using A/Bingo for Rails, and it seems to be working fine, except for counting conversions. It looks like conversions for the first user that converts are counted, but then it gets stuck and doesn't record any other conversions. I know that conversions occurred because I see them in **two** completely separate and unrelated analytics apps.

My test is called `body_background_white`, and is set up like this:

```
 #application.html.erb
 <% if (ab_test("body_background_white")) %>
 <body class="umbrella whitebg">
 <% else %>
 <body class="umbrella">
 <% end %>


# conversion trigger (not cached)
  def install
    bingo!("installation")
    # redirect_to "/images/pixel.gif"
    response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
    response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache"
    logger.info "Installation complete for ABingo participant #{session[:abingo_identity]}"
    logger.info "  Campaign data: #{cookies[:campaign_data].inspect}"
    logger.info "Cachebusting check: #{rand(10000)}"
    render :text => ""
  end

#log output
Installation complete for ABingo participant 3462657478
Cachebusting check: 2699
Completed in 2ms (View: 0, DB: 0) | 200 OK [/_conversions/install]

--
Installation complete for ABingo participant 1402985604
Cachebusting check: 5050
Completed in 2ms (View: 1, DB: 0) | 200 OK [/_conversions/install]

--
Installation complete for ABingo participant 5021442890
Cachebusting check: 6231
Completed in 2ms (View: 0, DB: 0) | 200 OK [/_conversions/install]

--
Installation complete for ABingo participant 9682352285
Cachebusting check: 6665
Completed in 2ms (View: 0, DB: 0) | 200 OK [/_conversions/install]
```

Do you know what might be causing the conversions (beyond those of the first user) not to register on the abingo dashboard page?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your code is not following the example listed here:
  http://www.bingocardcreator.com/abingo

I would conform to their example and see if that works.